# swipe function on slider

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can't seem to get it working trying to get slide function for next and prev slider does work without swipe of course. I am using swipeJs but with no success. here is the js...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    Slider = $('.slide-container').Swipe().data('Swipe');
    $('.next').on('click', Slider.next);
    $('.prev').on('click', Slider.prev);
});
```

and the html ...

```
<ul class="slides family animated">
        <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-1" checked />
        <li class="slide-container">
            <div class="slideM">
                <div id="company-title" class="animated pulse"><h2>title</h2></div></br>
<p class="animated bounceInLeft">content.</p>

<p class="box animated four flipInX boxGreen">content</p>
            </div>
            <div class="nav">

                <label for="img-2" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
            </div>
        </li>

        <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-2" />
        <li class="slide-container">
            <div class="slideM">
               <div id="family">
<p class="add-anim-up">content</p> </div></div>
 <div class="nav">
                <label for="img-1" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
                <label for="img-3" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
            </div>
        </li>   
</ul>
```

Comment: `data()` doesn't return a swipe instance by the look of the documentation it's not part of the Swipe API at all. If it's the jQuery one this will not return something where prev and next method are. Are Slider.prev/next not undefined if you output them?

Comment: i apologise for not knowing what you mean , could you explain ?

Comment: if it realtes to the html prev and next they are defined in css and are working without swipe of course

Comment: `Slider.next` as in your JS code. As in insert `console.log(Slider.next)` and check the console for the output.

Comment: put the code you mentioned in the jquery statement at top of this post and used developer tools to see what it was outputting , there was nothing there and can't use developer tools on a touch device